# regular expression

Tags: python, regex

i am looking to find some words in a string of code i've already done for my class. i want to find if the abstracts of the literature i found includes the words "gene" or "genetic". so far i have

```
match = re.search(r"(gene|tic)"
```

which gives me 44 results; however, this expression is pulling anything that has the words gene or genetic in them (like general or biotic). how can i change this to only pull either gene or genetic, and nothing else? this must be a regular expression.

Comment: Please include example cases with input and output, with both the desired result and the current invalid result.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should match only on the exact 3 words "gene", "genes" and "genetic"

```
re.search(r"(\bgene(tic|s)?\b)")
```

`\b` matches word boundaries (the beginning or end of a word) and `(tic|s)?` optionally matches the string "tic" or "s".

Comment: thanks! i was wondering, is there also a way for this code to show the word genes? so in total, gene, genetic, or genes?

Comment: @codingamateur yes, you just need to add `|s` to the optional match, I have updated the answer. `|` means "OR"

Answer (score 0):

Try `r"gene(?:tic)?"`
the tic is optional at the end.